# FDQuery.Refresh in a separate thread while LiveBindings AutoActive := true

Tags: listview, delphi, thread-safety

I have ListView1 livebinded with FDQuery1. I use IDThreadComponent1 to make changes to the database in a separate thread. After each such change, I run FDQuery1.Refresh to update my ListView1. If I do this in this way `IdThreadComponent1.Synchronize (RefreshMainQuery)`, then the UI of my app freeze for a second each time. I understand that this is because the LiveBindings mechanism is not thread-safe (I have `LinkListControlToField1.AutoActive := true`).
In this case, how to properly call FDQuery1.Refresh and not to freeze the user interface on each iteration?

```
procedure TfMain.IdThreadComponent1Run(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
begin
  ....
  UpdatePrices;
  ....
end;

procedure TfMain.RefreshMainQuery;
var ScrollPos: single;
begin
  ScrollPos := ListView1.ScrollViewPos; 
  FDQuery1.DisableControls;
  FDQuery1.Refresh;
  FDQuery1.EnableControls;
  ListView1.ScrollViewPos := ScrollPos;
end;

procedure TfMain.UpdatePrices;
begin
  FDQuery2.First;   
  while not FDQuery2.Eof do     
    begin
      ...
      UpdateStockStatus(1, FDQuery2.FieldByName('ItemID').Value);
      IdThreadComponent1.Synchronize(RefreshMainQuery); 
      //I need to do this after each iteration to visually change 
      //ListView1 and see which items are processed and which are not.
      FDQuery2.Next;    
    end;
end;
```

If to do so:

```
LinkListControlToField1.Active: = false;
FDQuery1.Refresh;
LinkListControlToField1.Active: = true;
```

then my ListView1 goes blank for a second, which is also very bad.

Comment: How many records does your FDQuery retreive?  Does it make any difference it you move the ListView1.ScrollPos:= ... to before the call to EnableControls?

Comment: @MartynA, about 2000-3000 records. You can comment out EnableControls/DisableControls, these are just artifacts of my ugly "experiments".

Comment: When updating a lot of list view items it is advised to do ListView.Items.BeginUpdate/EndUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping multiple updates to list items in BeginUpdate/EndUpdate can usually help. I don't use livebindings often myself so not sure if that changes the situation.

```
procedure TfMain.RefreshMainQuery;
var ScrollPos: single;
begin
  ScrollPos := ListView1.ScrollViewPos; 
  Try
    ListView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
    FDQuery1.Refresh;
  finally
    ListView1.Items.EndUpdate;
    ListView1.ScrollViewPos := ScrollPos;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @brain, adding ListView1.BeginUpdate/EndUpdate didn't change anything.